# calling other contract's function dynamically

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to create a function in Solidity that would call an arbitrary function on an arbitrary contract with all the parameters?

In JavaScript I would write something like this

```
function callArbitrary(contract, func, params){
    contract[func](params);
}
```

is there a solidity version of that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is generally not recommended if you're not sure what you are doing, since it can open a lot of security holes, and it is best to only call contracts that are known beforehand.

That said, the technique looks like this:

```
address myContract = 0xabcdef....;
myContract.call.gas(msg.gas-3000).value(1 ether)(bytes4(sha3("myFunction(uint256,bytes32,string)")), 42, 0xabc, "hello")
```

Essentially, you use the `call` method of an address, then use the `gas` and `value` properties to add gas and value (you may ommit the value if it is 0). Then you pass in the first 4 bytes of the sha3 hash of the function you wish to call.

Comment: thank you for the answer. But is the second line correct? it looks like it should be `myContract.call`

Comment: Nice catch, yes it should

Comment: I do not think this is really the answer: In this answer the parameters need to be known at compile time (since you explicitly pass them as `42, 0xabc, "hello"` but even having them as variables you need to know the number of parameters and their types). I guess there should be a way to simply pass arbitrary callData (as `bytes`?) but I cant figure out how to do that.

Comment: You're right, this isn't a fully general answer, but I think it's a bit more clear than just passing in a `bytes` containing all of the calldata. If you want a fully general proxy, you can take a look at the [uport proxy](https://github.com/zmitton/uport-contracts/blob/develop/contracts/proxies/Proxy.sol#L51)

Comment: @TjadenHess do you have an example of serializing the data for this proxy function?